# Are there any good studies on daily kcal intake?

Tags: diet

It's a well known "fact" that an average men should consume about 2500kcal per day but having checked my intake this sounds ridiculously high (by about a factor of 2.25 in my case). Some studies with self-reported kcal intake seem to match the recommendation fairly well. Wikipedia lists countries with an average intake per capita of over 3000kcal.

This makes me wonder for example as to how high variation in intake is and what this 2500kcal recommendation actually means.

Are there estimates on what daily intake looked like over history? Such as 5 centuries ago, 2000 years ago etc.

Comment: It is not a well known "Fact" that 2500. Is "considered" to suffice for an average man per day. However, how exactly your body receives these calories is a determining factor. A man could live on 1000 per day. However if it's only from McDonalds cheese burgers, the proper nutrients will not be delivered. There are also few studies on this due to the fact that we didn't have modern medicine and studies centuries ago. This is something that needs to be studied. Unfortunately the amount of variables that come into play hinder that greatly.

Comment: Different individuals have different metabolisms.  You just have to keep a log to find out what's right for *you*.